# Call static class methods in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

How I can call a static class method from another static class method?

```
Class MyClass{

    static [String] Method1(){
        return "Hello";
    }

    static [String] Method2(){
        # Call another static method from the same class
        return  Method1() + "World"; 
    }

}
```

I have tried `[MyClass]::Method1()` but I wan to know if there is any shorter.

Comment: No that's it. Why would length matter? These are .net classes and methods and there are no shortcuts for such a language. Maybe provide some context into what are you looking for with "shorter".

Comment: You can always wrap a static method call in a PowerShell function if you need it shortened for some reason.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell: How to call a static method from the other static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66322790/powershell-how-to-call-a-static-method-from-the-other-static-method)