# Powershell: How to call a static method from the other static method

Tags: powershell

I have a class of "utils" and some of the static methods. I want to call one method from the other. If I use $this it will tell me "Cannot access the non-static member 'this' in a static method or initializer of a static property." but without $this it can't find the method. I also don't want to hard code the class name - but if this is the only solution then I have to.
Can you please shed some lights here?
Environment: Win10/Powershell 7.1
Below please find the code

```
class MyDateUtils
{
    
    Static [DateTime] ToLocalTime([String]$fromDate,[String]$fromTZ, [String]$format)
    {
    
        if($fromTZ -eq $null -or $fromTZ -eq "")
        {
            $fromTZ = 'Eastern Standard Time'
        }
        
        $tz = [TimeZoneInfo]::FindSystemTimeZoneById($fromTZ)

        $nominalDate = FormatDate($fromDate, $format)

        $utcOffset = $tz.GetUtcOffset($nominalDate)

        $dto = [DateTimeOffset]::new($nominalDate.Ticks, $utcOffset)

        return $dto.LocalDateTime

       
    }
    
    Static [DateTime] FormatDate([String]$date)
    {
        return FormatDate($date, $null)
    }

    Static [DateTime] FormatDate([String]$date,[String]$format)
    {
    
        #$dateString = $date.split(' ')[0]
    
        if($format -ne $null -and $format -ne "")
        {
            return [Datetime]::ParseExact( $date, $format, $null)
        }
    
    
        $formatList =  'MM/dd/yyyy', 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss', 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm',`
                       'M/d/yyyy', 'M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss', 'M/d/yyyy HH:mm',  
                       'MM/d/yyyy', 'MM/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss', 'MM/d/yyyy HH:mm',
                       'M/dd/yyyy', 'M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss',    'M/dd/yyyy HH:mm',
                       'yyyy-MM-dd', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'
    
    
        $result = $null
    
        foreach($f in $formatList)
        {
          try{
            $result = [Datetime]::ParseExact( $date, $f, $null)
          }catch {
            
          }
          
          if($result -ne $null)
          {
            return $result
          }
        }
    
        return $result
    }
    
    


}
```

Then if I ran below from command line I got the error below:

```
[MyDateUtils]::ToLocalTime('2021-02-23 07:10', $null, $null)
line |
  14 |          $nominalDate = FormatDate($fromDate, $format)
     |                         ~~~~~~~~~~
     | The term 'FormatDate' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable
     | program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
     | and try again.
```

if I added a $this prior to the FormatDate it then populated the static/this error
Appreciate for your help

Comment: I think this is the only way: `[MyDateUtils]::FormatDate($fromDate, $format)`

Comment: Thanks @zett42. sounds like so. My concern is if late the class name is changed I would have to update the reference :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't want to hard code the class name - but if this is the only solution then I have to.

Indeed, **unlike in C#, for example, you *have to use the class name explicitly* to refer to a *static* member of your class even from inside that class**:

Using simplified examples:

The (near)-equivalent of the following C# class:

```cs
// C#
public class Foo {
  public static string Bar() {
    // Calling fellow static function Baz() requires NO qualifier.
    return Baz();
  }
  static string Baz() {
    return "baz C#";
  }
}
```

in PowerShell is the following:

```
# PowerShell
class Foo {
  static [string] Bar() {
    # To call the fellow static Baz() method,
    # you MUST use the class name explicitly.
    # Otherwise, due to PowerShell's *dynamic scoping*, PowerShell would 
    # look for a command named 'Baz' in the enclosing scope and its ancestors.
    return [Foo]::Baz()
  }
  hidden static [string] Baz() {
    return 'baz'
  }
}
```

<sup>Note: `Baz()` without qualifier and *without arguments* would actually be *syntax* error, but with one ore more arguments PowerShell indeed would look for a command named `Baz` at runtime - even though using *method* syntax (argument list enclosed in `(...)` and arguments separated by `,`) is *inappropriate* for *commands* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65208621/45375) for more information.</sup>

**PowerShell *always* requires an explicit qualifier for class-internal member access:**

- `$this` is required for *instance* members; e.g., `$this.PropA` is needed to access an instance property declared as `[string] $PropA`, and `$this.OtherMethod()` calls fellow instance method `OtherMethod`.
- For *static* members, an object representing the class itself, which is a *type literal* in the simplest case, such as `[Foo]`, and notably also `::` rather than `.`, as shown above.

See the conceptual [about_Classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Classes) help topic for more information.

**While the automatic (implicitly declared) `$this` variable is a convenient abstraction to refer to a class' *instance*, no analogous variable exists for the *class itself***, invariably resulting in needing to *repeat* the class name inside the class, which is both somewhat cumbersome and a maintenance concern.

**If - and only if - you're referencing a static member *from an instance member***, you can **work around** the need to repeat the class name by using **`$this.GetType()`**:

```
class Foo {
  # Bar() is now an *instance* method.
  [string] Bar() {
    # Because $this is now defined to refer to the instance,
    # you can use $this.GetType() to refer to the class.
    return $this.GetType()::Baz()
  }
  hidden static [string] Baz() {
    return 'baz'
  }
}

[Foo]::new().Bar() # -> 'baz'
```

---

Certainly, **having an automatic variable analogous to `$this` would help matters, such as `$thisType`** (`$thisClass` would be semantically too narrow if *interface* definitions were to be supported in the future).

If you feel strongly enough about having such a variable, I encourage you to [create a feature request in PowerShell's GitHub repo](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/new/choose).

Note:

- One general concern when introducing new [automatic variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables)  are potential name collisions, given PowerShell's dynamic scoping.
- Classes were introduced late in the evolution of PowerShell, and while PowerShell fully supports interacting with preexisting .NET classes (types), defining them in PowerShell itself is a less pressing need, especially for casual use (where ad hoc objects created with `[pscustomobject] @{ ... }` will often do). While PowerShell's class support will never catch up to C#'s, a variety of improvements *are* being considered - see [GitHub issue #6652](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6652).

Comment: Thank you so much for all these details @mklement0! I'm considering to raise a request to Powershell :)